# Paraview colormaps to MATLAB

Tags: matlab, colormap, paraview, color-space, lab-color-space

I'm trying to 'borrow' some colormaps from Paraview to MATLAB (found in this [link](https://kitware.github.io/paraview-docs/latest/python/_modules/paraview/_colorMaps.html)) to implement my own colormaps. However, some colormaps are supposedly written in the LAB space, for example this **BuRd** colormap

```xml
<ColorMap name="BuRd" space="Lab">
<Point x="-1" o="1" r="0.019608" g="0.188235" b="0.380392"/>
<Point x="-0.87451" o="1" r="0.088504" g="0.321107" b="0.564937"/>
<Point x="-0.74902" o="1" r="0.163399" g="0.444983" b="0.697501"/>
<Point x="-0.623529" o="1" r="0.247059" g="0.555709" b="0.754095"/>
<Point x="-0.498039" o="1" r="0.420684" g="0.676432" b="0.818685"/>
<Point x="-0.372549" o="1" r="0.606459" g="0.789773" b="0.880277"/>
<Point x="-0.247059" o="1" r="0.761476" g="0.868512" b="0.924567"/>
<Point x="-0.121569" o="1" r="0.878047" g="0.925721" b="0.951942"/>
<Point x="0.00392157" o="1" r="0.969089" g="0.966474" b="0.964937"/>
<Point x="0.129412" o="1" r="0.983852" g="0.897578" b="0.846828"/>
<Point x="0.254902" o="1" r="0.982468" g="0.800692" b="0.706113"/>
<Point x="0.380392" o="1" r="0.960323" g="0.66782" b="0.536332"/>
<Point x="0.505882" o="1" r="0.894579" g="0.503806" b="0.399769"/>
<Point x="0.631373" o="1" r="0.81707" g="0.33218" b="0.281046"/>
<Point x="0.756863" o="1" r="0.728489" g="0.155017" b="0.197386"/>
<Point x="0.882353" o="1" r="0.576932" g="0.055363" b="0.14925"/>
<Point x="1" o="1" r="0.403922" g="0" b="0.121569"/>
</ColorMap>
```

However, the r/g/b values here do not look like belong to the LAB space; they still look like regular RGB values. I tried to use the MATLAB built-in function `lab2rgb` to convert them to RGB values anyway, but some negative values are generated, which are unacceptable for `colormap` in MATLAB. If I directly use these values as if they are RGB, the resulting colors do not look like as they should be.

Does any one know how to implement this colormap in MATLAB?

Thanks!

Comment: Where it says “r=…, g=…, b=…” you have RGB values. If they don’t look like they should, there might be some monitor calibration missing.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I don't think it's the monitor or anything like that. The resulting colors are way off, it's like from warm color to cool color that kind of off.

Comment: When they say colormaps were made in the LAB space, they mean the design waas made in LAB, but they are given to you in RGB. This is because LAB is good for perceptual change of color measurement, so it is good science to design colormaps there. Unless they have some sort of weirdly scaled LAB space representation, those numbers are not in the right scale for LAB.

Comment: Also, consider having a look at the various MATLAB implemented FEX colormaps, maybe you have there what you want.

Comment: I don’t know, the values *look* like RGB values. If they’re not? It’ll be hard to learn how they’re encodes. You’d have to find the source code that used these maps and see what it did to them. Lab usually has values in a very different range from 0-1, which is what you have here.